# Accessing a BelongsTo Element in Ember when all information is not brought down via Ajax

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember-Data and Ember-CLI and I have two Ember Models;

clip.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   scene: DS.belongsTo('scene') 
});
```

scene.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   clip: DS.belongsTo('clip') 
});
```

Clips are loaded independantly from Scenes, so when scenes come down the JSON looks like this;

```
{scenes: [{id: 1, clip_id: 5}, {id:2, clip_id:10}]}
```

The clip_id does correspond to a clip already loaded into Ember.

What I would like to be able to do is call `scene.clip.name`

Can anyone recommend what I need to do to get this up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark clip as async.  Additionally the format your are using foo`_id` isn't standard with the `DS.RESTAdapter`.  It just expects `foo`.  You can use the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` which does expect it in that format.

```
clip: DS.belongsTo('clip', {async:true})
```

Then it's an async property, so you need to use a `then` when accessing it the first time (or anytime if you want, or aren't guaranteed that it's been fetched).

```
scene.get('clip').then(function(clip){
  console.log(clip.get('name'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I should have said as well as being independant from scenes, clips are already fully loaded in the system.

I will change the API to see if that works, thanks again.

Comment: mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, that's what you meant by `The clip_id does correspond to a clip already in the system`, sorry I thought you meant on the back end.

Comment: For anyone else reading this answer, the part that helped me specifically was that RESTAdapter didn't expect `_id`, in my case I controlled the API as well so made the change there.